# Suggested approach to generate pages based on attributes on properties in model in ASP.Net MVC!

Tags: asp.net-mvc

We need to generate forms for Create/Display/Edit on our website. The requirement is that these need to be metadata driven. We will have properties on our Model attributed with the type of control to generate for that property.

```
[RenderAs("DatePicker", Order = 1)]
public DateTime DateOfBirth{get; set;}
```

The idea is to have templates for each of these like Date-Picker.ascx, etc in the SharedFolder
We need to generate around 25 such forms and are looking for a reuseable way of accomplishing this. What would be the best way to handle validations with this (basic validations like required, less than, greater than, etc)? What do you suggest for dependent field validations (less than field, greater than field)? Does this sound sensible?

Thanks

Comment: ever heard of mvc2 templated helpers, or mvccontrib's inputbuilders ?

Comment: Yes, that what we are using. Now her's the difficult part.

Comment: We have templates for Title, Description, etc. The Title field is called title in one model and Name in another. How do we get the labels correct in such cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for MVC 2 templates.

Use DisplayForModel for read only views and EditorForModel for create/edit forms built from the metadata in your view model.  Use Data Annotations attributes to decorate the view model with validation rules and other rendering information (label, custom template to use, etc.).

Here's a quick [intro video to MVC 2 templates](http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos/mvc2-template-customization).

Answer (score 1):

Check out [ASP.Net Dynamic Data](http://www.asp.net/dynamicdata).  It is pretty much what you are looking for.  (And if you can use .Net 4.0 then you should be able to use MVC, webforms, and DynamicData all in one project.)

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing Model and View concept. Why do you need MVC THEN?

On practice, you will face situations when Admin need some minor changes compared to regular user, and it will be hard to support in cases when form is generated using attributes.

I am not saying this is best, but we decided to stick with form concept and every form able to decide WHAT to show and HOW to show. 
And we defined number of helper methods like RenderDatePicker which do all dirty work.

Comment: The admin will probably not change the forms. We just need a faster way of doing 25+ crud forms.